# How to reload CVCalendar when getting api response in swift

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am using [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) to display calendar with events. But the events are loading from the rest api call . I cant update the the events in the calendar after getting response.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used that library before, but looking around at the API, there are various "reload" methods in the different classes. If you look at the demo project the `CVCalendarMonthContentViewController` view controller has a method `reloadMonthViews`. I suggest you take a look at that, as well as the reload methods in the view classes.

Comment: Hi Duncan, I'm facing the same issue as azhar. I tried to call the reloadMonthViews, but was met with a "unexpectedly found nil" error. Azhar, did you manage to find a solution to your problem? If so, please share. Thanks.

Comment: An "unexpectedly found nil" error just means that you have an optional somewhere that contains nil and you need to track it down and figure out why it's nil. Normal Swift debugging stuff.

Comment: Ok, I now know where my error was.  However, I'm now unable to call method CVCalendarMonthContentViewController.reloadMonthViews() method. It says I'm required to pass in an argument to make the call.

Comment: To repeat, I've never used the `CVCalendarMonthContentViewController` library before, and don't know anything about it other than what I learned from glancing at the docs. You are in a better position to figure out the problems you're having than I am. If it's telling you you need to pass a parameter to the method `reloadMonthViews` then you need to go figure out what parameter it expects and provide it.

Comment: @mechdon please check this link [CVCalendar issue](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar/issues/80) i think it helps you.

Comment: Thanks azhar and duncan

Answer (score 0):

As per too much search i found this magic line of code, and it works for me 
Use below the function in CVCalendarView,and pass `NSDate()` as argument

```
public func reloadMonthView(selectedDate: NSDate) {
            let newController: ContentController

            contentController.updateHeight(contentController.presentedMonthView.potentialSize.height, animated: true)
            newController = MonthContentViewController(calendarView: self, frame: bounds, presentedDate: selectedDate)

            newController.updateFrames(bounds)
            newController.scrollView.alpha = 0
            addSubview(newController.scrollView)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.contentController.scrollView.alpha = 0
                newController.scrollView.alpha = 1
                }) { _ in
                    self.contentController.scrollView.removeAllSubviews()
                    self.contentController.scrollView.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.contentController = newController
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try following way

```
self.calendarView.contentController.refreshPresentedMonth()
```